# Add a decorator to a new property with a class decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

Pretty much all of I want to know is in the title.
I would like to know how to add a new property with its own decorators with a class decorator.

I want to create a class decorator Api(string[]) which expose the class methods listed in the class decorator.
To do that I want to emit an event with `EventEmitter` from Angular, to do that I have to add the `@Output()` decorator to a new property.

Can I?

Following an exemple: I just have MyClass with methods process, open, close.
I would like to create decorator(s?) to expose whatever methods I want (here, open and close). I imagined a class decorator which adds the `api` property and a method decorator to expose a method, maybe?

```
class MyClass {
  @Output() api = new EventEmitter();

  $exposedMethods: object = {};

  constructor() {
    this.$exposedMethods = {
      open: this.open.bind(this),
      close: this.close.bind(this)
    };
    this.api.emit(this.$exposedMethods);
  }

  process() {

  }

  open() {
    // stuff...
  }

  close() {
    // stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: Plrase provide a [mcve] of what you want **without** a decorator, and we'll change it with a decorator doign the exact same thing.

Comment: Done, sorry for the lack of example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who were looking for way to dynamically add `@Output` to component (for patch purposes for example) I leave solution for project I work on - you can use directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'your-component',
})
export class PatchDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @Output()
  yourEvent = new EventEmitter();

  private patchMethod() {
    const orgFn = this.method;

    this.method = () => {
      orgFn();
      this.yourEvent.emit(args);
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so brace yourself because this is a **very hard concept** to grasp.

You have the live demo here :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kxtzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

For the code :

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

const Expose: (methods: string[]) => ClassDecorator = (methods) => {

  return component => {

    for (const method of methods) {
      const eventEmitterName = `${method}Emitter`;
      component.prototype[eventEmitterName] = new EventEmitter();

      const outputFactory = Output(method);

      const orgFn = component.prototype[method];

      component.prototype[method] = (...args) => {
        orgFn(...args);
        component.prototype[eventEmitterName].emit();
      }

      outputFactory(component.prototype, eventEmitterName);
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<button (click)="open()">Emit an open event</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
@Expose(['open'])
export class HelloComponent {

  @Input() name: string;

  open() {
    console.log('Clicked on the button, now emitting an event');
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Class decorators are functions.
In your case, this is a class decorator factory : you provide parameters, and it should return a class decorator. This is the signature you can see :

```
const Expose: (methods: string[]) => ClassDecorator = (methods) => { ... }
```

It declares `Expose` to be a factory that returns a Class Decorator. Your factory accepts a list of methods as the parameters.

Now, this factory needs to return a class decorator. A class decorator is a function that has the component itself as the only parameter. This is the line

```
return component => { ... }
```

It returns a function complying with the `ClassDecorator` signature.

After that, you need to rewrite each of your methods. So you'll loop over them with a simple loop.

In the loop, we will create a new event emitter. To make it simple, we will use the name `[method]Emitter`. So we start by creating the holy name :

```
const eventEmitterName = `${method}Emitter`;
```

Once this is done, we bind it to the component's prototype :

```
component.prototype[eventEmitterName] = new EventEmitter();
```

You now have your event emitter.

After that, you will need to bind the output decorator to it. If you followed the first steps, you will understand that `Output` is actually also a factory. This means it returns a `MethodDecorator` function, whose signature is

```
(component, methodKey) => { ... }
```

(There's a third parameter called the descriptor, but you don't need it, so I will ignore it).

Once this is known, we grab our factory result for our method :

```
const outputFactory = Output(method);
```

This will create an output named after your method (here being `open`).

Once this is done, we will override the given method to emit an event when its processing is done.

This is basic JS function overriding :

```
const orgFn = component.prototype[method];

component.prototype[method] = (...args) => {
  orgFn(...args);
  component.prototype[eventEmitterName].emit();
}
```

At the last line, we emit the event through the previously created event emitter.

Now, all we have left to do is bind this event emitter to our component. To do that, we simply call the method decorator created by the output factory.

```
outputFactory(component.prototype, eventEmitterName);
```

Now, your decorator is complete and working. As you can see on the stackblitz, the code in the `open` function is being run, then once ran, the code for the `(open)` output in tha app component template is ran.

And **Voilààààà !**

Comment: And of course, I didn't code what you wanted but the principle behind it (I'm not here to code for you) : if you want to return a function of your child component, you will have to slightly change your decorator. Nothing too hard, don't worry, I'm sure you got it.

Comment: What an explanation! Better than posting the solution, I now understand better what an actual decorator is doing, thank you sir. Indeed, with your help, I can manage to do it on my own now. Wish I could upvote your solution more than once. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad you understood it, good luck with your project :) If you feel this answers your question, feel free to mark it as resolved and/or upvote my answer to put it on the top of the page !

Comment: I sure did! Thank you again!

Comment: Hi again, so I thought I was done with this, but... no. I don't get why. When I have multiple same component on the same page, the event is raised just for the last one. I don't get why tho' :(

Comment: Okay, found it. In your example, you attach the eventemitter to the prototype.  Which, i don't want to, I had to instantiate the evenemitter inside my class constructor to do this

Comment: @ChainList I bind it to the prototype because in a constructor, the target (`component`) isn't instanciated yet, so you can't have access to its properties. I Don't exactly know what you have tried, but it seems that the issue could be the name of the variable. Try generating random names for your event emitters, this could resolve your issue as well.